# I want navigate to particular div in another html. Why this code is doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, web, bootstrap-4

This is the second HTML page navbar coding...

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li><a href="./index.html#mypage">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="./index.html#about">ABOUT US</a></li>
<li><a href="./index.html#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is the main HTML page (index.html)

```
<div id="about" class="container text-center">
<h3>THE KUBERA LAKSHMI POOJA PRODUCTS</h3>
<p><em>All type of pooja products are available here!</em></p>
<p>We have all types of divine items such as herbal and pooja products. The utilizations of our products are utilized in temple and home.</p>
<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the path is not good I think they should add ./
I am not testing but you can try :)

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li><a href="./index.html#mypage">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="./index.html#about">ABOUT US</a></li>
<li><a href="./index.html#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: yet it should work what you did!

You should already create the other 2 id if you have not done so yet because I see that the id is about

Comment: sorry, the 1st id(index.html#mypage) is only working another 2 id(index.html#about and index.html#contact) is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<li><a href="#mypage">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">ABOUT US</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
```

to navigate on the same page.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-href